# Dynamic global replacement with line numbers, emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to do some debugging on some Prolog code, and I have several calls to a method.

Is it possible to do a global replace within emacs so that I could create a write statement that would displace the current line in the program?

Essentially, assuming a method call X and a write statement write(some string), could I replace all the instances of

X,

with

X, write(LINE-NUMBER)

where LINE-NUMBER was obtained through some emacs call?

Please let me know if I'm not being clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/06/shiny-and-new-emacs-22.html)
has a similar example.

From it, I tried the following command

```
M-x replace-regexp
Replace regexp: \(word_to_replace\)
Replace regexp with: \1, write(\,(line-number-at-pos)
```

The `replace-regexp` can be heavy handed, so you must be careful with
the regex you use for the pattern.  `M-x query-replace-regexp` may
be useful too, if there are not too many matches.

Comment: Even if there are many matches, `query-replace-regexp` is usually just fine (`!` will replace them all).  Note also that nowadays the preferred way to run `query-replace-regexp` is to start with `C-s` (or `C-u C-s`), then enter your search key incrementally, then hit `M-%`.